# div position absolute height 100%

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

How can i make a div, which position is absolute, expand height 100%?
The div has dynamic content.

Right now the div doesn't expand if i added more content. If i added the height like 400px it expand.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <div class="navLeftBox">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Stuff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav{
    background: #c7c7c7;
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    height: 33px;
    width: 968px;
    padding: 14px 0 0 30px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
}
.navLeftBox {
    background: #bcbcbc;
    border: 1px solid #939393;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    clear:both;
}
```

I also added it on jsfiffle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4HnA/)**

Thank you!

Comment: Absolute with `clear: both`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not specify a height the height of the unit automatically adjusts to the content or set to `heigth:auto;`
ie you need to set the `heigth:auto;` or simply remove

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4HnA/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Or just remove the `height:100%`.

```
.navLeftBox {
    background: #bcbcbc;
    border: 1px solid #939393;
    width:200px;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    clear:both;
}
```